# How to translate order purchase date filter (sales module) - Magento 2

Tags: php, date, magento2, uicomponents

in admin magento 2, we can see the order filter, one of the filters consist in purchase date, from - to. I need know, how can i translate it to dd/MM/y format?

Note the default format of this date is: MM/dd/y

Any response will be apreciate

Comment: What language do you need to use? Not sure, but maybe installing some european language package, also the data will be printed as you wish. Just a guess...

Comment: I can change for any language in admin of magento 2. This filter does not change this format. I would like pt_BR, but i dont care if have one solution in en_UK for example, because the date is on the same format.

Comment: i don't have time to test it right now, but i will leave you some interesting references about your problem: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190798/how-to-change-date-format-for-order-invoices-in-magento-2    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151253/how-to-change-date-format-of-magento-2-admin-grid-filter-without-using-ui-compon   https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107733/magento-2-how-to-set-format-datetime-for-all-system hope these help